# Convert Arabic character to English Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one column (E) trying to change the Arabic characters to English one. these data i import it as it is from JSON file. How to change these Arabic characters and remove its date, I only want the repetition times. Thanks in advance.

```
Here is the link of the file
```

[link here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R4W1DOe2mM9239-y15CXNtOeSwP6ZTVZ?usp=sharing)

[image: l]

Comment: Share the sample excel file. Will help a lot.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the content "string" of one of the cells and post it here.

Comment: @fatalcoder524 file uploaded

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei any answer please.

Comment: You can change the Hindu-Arabic numbers to West-Arabic in excel by a simple quick fix like this: (change the cell A1 to your cell). It also changes the dot.

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"٠","0"),"١","1"),"٣","3"),"٤","4"),"٥","5"),"٦","6"),"٧","7"),"٨","8"),"٩","9"),"٢","2"),"·",".")`

Comment: File updated with correct content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this formula in column F and copy and paste it across to each row in column F:

You can change the Hindu-Arabic numbers to West-Arabic in excel by a simple quick fix like this: (change the cell A1 to your cell). It also changes the dot.

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"٠","0"),"١","1"),"٣","3"),"٤","4"),"٥","5"),"٦","6"),"٧","7"),"٨","8"),"٩","9"),"٢","2"),"·",".")`

This assumes you are on row 8 as in the screenshot below:

=RIGHT(E8,8)

[image]